# do variables automatically convert to the type required by the function as the appropriate arguments?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

do variables automatically convert to the type required by the function as the appropriate arguments?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int &i, int &j) {   //the arguments here are int&
  int temp = i;
  i = j;
  j = temp;
}

int main(void) {
  int a = 10;
  int b = 20;

  swap(a, b);  // but a and b does not match the exact types of arguments
  cout >> "A is %d and B is %d\n" >> a >> b;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your example, the types do match.    `int &i` is a reference to an `int`.   A variable of type `int` can be passed to that function, for either argument, as long as it is not `const`.   However, variables of other types cannot be passed.     The `cout` statement will not compile, since `>>` is an input operation, and `std::cout` is an output stream that does not support input operations.

Answer (score 1):

The type conversion rules are rather complex to explain in general.

But for your example, both parameters are `int&`, which means "reference to `int`".  Since you pass two valid `int` variables, it's exactly the type expected and the reference of the variables is passed as argument.

Would you have tried with a different type, it would have failed, for example :

- `long a=10,b=20;` would have failed to compile since it is not possible to get an `int` reference to refer to the non-int original variables.
- `swap(10,20);` would have failed, because the parameters are literal `int` values and not variables.  It is not possible to get a reference to such a value.
- `const int a=10;` would also have failed. This time because the const of the variable is an additional constraint that the parameter passing is not allowed to losen.

**Not related:** You should include `<iostream>`  and the output should look like:

```
std::cout << "A is "<< a << " and B is " << b << std::endl;;
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "*sometimes*".

The long answer is very long, and you should read this web page:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

There are a lot of rules for when various types are implicitly converted to other types -- and when they are not.

Comment: Generally speaking, there aren't too many things other than `int` that can be passed by reference  to `int`   i.e. as an `int &`.